# .htaccess Query String ? Instead of &

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website I want to rewrite URLs From

http://myexampledomain.com/index.php?page=about

To

http://myexampledomain.com/about

So, in order to achieve this I did fix my `.htaccess` code like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^api/([^/]*)$ api/$1 [L]
```

Now, my problem is when I need to send query string to my page URLS I need to do like

http://myexampledomain.com/about&myquery1=value&myquery2=value

I should start like `&myquery1=value&myquery2=value` instead of `?myquery1=value&myquery2=value` because first `?` is already been used in .htaccess.

But now, I need this fixed and I should be able to access my domain like

http://myexampledomain.com/about?myquery1=value&myquery2=value

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add `QSA` flag in your rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` (Query String Append) flag preserves existing query parameters while adding a new one.